# excel .xlsb file slow when closing and saving after changed from .xlsm file

Tags: excel, excel-2007

i have excel .xlsm file format with about 20000kb file size..i have a macro inside it but the macro runs ok and fast. the problems is it is very slow during opening and closing,taking about few minutes.i then try to change it to .xlsb file format which reduce its size to 2000kb (very huge difference) and the file run fast while opening but still very slow when closing or saving. sometimes closing it make the excel 'not responding'. i have no macro running when opening or closing event. any suggestion on what caused this?

Comment: Do you perhaps have links to other workbooks or you are using volatile functions ?

http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur i have no links to other workbooks and i use no function in the worksheet.my program is all about importing data from text files.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the Office file validation slowing things down. Microsoft Update (KB 2501584) can really be a problem while it does it's security checking on a file.

Comment: the OFV add ins is not installed on the excel. what i know is the OFV addins caused the excel file slow during the opening but what i'm facing right now is it running very slow during closing or saving,even sometimes make the excel not responding

Comment: does it matter where you save to? a local versus network location? Or where the file was opened from. And it isn't a shared workbook in anyway right? Calculation is set to manual or automatic on the file saving?

Comment: no it isn't a shared workbook nor located on the network drive.i already set the calculation to manual but it still stuck while saving or closing.

Comment: as found on google, i've tried to add new blank vba module then save(which still take longer time).i then close the workbook and reopen it.now when i close the workbook without saving, it close faster than before but if i close and save, the same problem occur.it take a very long time to close and also not responding.

Comment: sounds like you have considered all this, but make sure max iterations is not too high, and if calculation is manual that recalculate before save is not a culprit and you have checked for circular references or other formulas trying to resolve